# How to make video with full height

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need your help to make this video with full height. Although, the div size is around 50% and when i make my video fixed position, it works like full background video but i want to make it fit into my div with full height.

Have look what i want [Here](http://client-acumenadagency.com/sed/)

You can check my video html code

```html
 <div class="video">
   <div id="video-holder" style="width:100%; position: absolute; height: auto !important; max-height:100%;">
 <video id="video" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            
 </video>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to have a video of that vertical mode ratio like 400px X 800px. I meant more height than width. Once you have the correct video - change your .video-holder class height to 100% so that it covers parent space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following CSS for the video tag?:

```
{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Given the example you mention this seems to put the video to a 100% of the height. If this is not exactly what you need just give us some more detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you also help me to make video brogressbar in circle ? @dncolomer 53

Comment: What do you mean exactly in circle? Do you have any example?

Comment: Never styled a prorgess tag element before but here you have some insights on HMTL5 progress styling maybe this will help you: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/