# How to set video tag to full height relative to its parent div?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently creating a single page video playing for store advertisement.

My problem is how can i set the video tag to full height relative to its parent div? I used vh dimension but still no luck to solve that.

As you can see on the image the video portion has gaps on both its top and bottom. already set the padding and margin to 0.
[image]

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- http://www.101computing.net/html-website-layout/ -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
  BODY {
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  .page {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .pageClockPanel {
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 60%;
    height: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .pageRightPanel {
    background-color: #1A237E;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 40%;
    height: 87%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .pageLeftPanel {
    background-color: #E64A19;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 60%;
    height: 77%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .pageBottomPanel {
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    clear: none;
    height: 13%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
  }


  .item img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 77vh
  }

  .item video,
  source {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 77vh;
  }
</style>

<title>Page Title</title>
<!-- https://www.bootply.com/59900 -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="pageClockPanel">

    </div>
    <div class="pageRightPanel">

    </div>
    <div class="pageLeftPanel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="item">
            <video video autobuffer autoplay> 
           <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
         </video>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageBottomPanel">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make video with full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612353/how-to-make-video-with-full-height)

Comment: thanks sir but doesn't work the way i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this css

```
.item{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item video {
            min-width: 100%; 
            min-height: 100%;
            height:auto;
}
```

[css explanation here](http://www.codesynthesis.co.uk/tutorials/html-5-full-screen-and-responsive-videos)

Answer (score 0):

The video tag get always the same ratios (width/height) as the video file.
It would looks like stretched if you want to fit the width and the height - if this is just possible.
You can try to set the height attribute of the video tag